# Convert terms into url names in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

let's suppose I had a column A in google sheets holding terms like

- Mäx Mustermann GmbH
- Diesdas& Company

that I would like to convert to url names like

- maex-mustermann-gmbh
- Diesdasand-company

So basically trying to make the word "url" friendly.
Is this something that is possible in google sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try on-

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]", ""),"[ ]","-")
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly! Is it also possible to make everything in lower cases? (I know this is a new requirement).

Comment: Yes, just use `Lower()` function beginning of the formula.